# How to strip from string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to append all the link in array "get_link".

```
get_link = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a.get_text(strip=True):
     get_link .append(a['href'])
```

Output of get_link:

```
['index.html?country=2',
 'index.html?country=25',
 'index.html?country=1',
 'index.html?country=6',
 'index.html?country=2']
```

How to get the following output?

```
[country=2',
 country=25',
 country=1',
 country=6',
 country=2']
```

Comment: I don't understand what your asking. Your title has little or nothing to do with the code you've shown. Are you just trying to figure out how to get the `country=...` part of each of your `index.html?country=...` strings? That seems like it would be easy with `str.index` and a slice, but I'm going to write up an answer saying that when I'm not at all sure that's actually what you're asking about.

Comment: @Blckknght  my english is not good that's why I couldn't explain better. is there any way to use right, left function with an array so that I can keep only necessary text of array get_link

Comment: I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you mean by "right, left function". If all your links are the same kind (they always start with `index.html?` and that's what you want to cut off, you might be able to do `get_link.append(a['href'][11:])`. The `[11:]` is a slice that cuts off the first 11 characters. If your links can look different though, you might need more sophisticated logic.

Comment: get_link.append(a['href'][11:]) it has worked. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The optimized approach to get all `a` tags(links) with non-empty text value and `href` attribute:

```
links = [l.get('href').replace('index.html?','') 
         for l in soup.find_all('a', href=True, string=True) if l.text.strip()]
print(links)
```

Comment: Yes, This is another way to remove "index.html?" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get only "country=" some are already in bs4 but if you want you can use regex :

```
import re
ui=['index.html?country=2',
 'index.html?country=25',
 'index.html?country=1',
 'index.html?country=6',
 'index.html?country=2']





pattern=r'(country=[0-9]{0,99})'



print("\n".join([re.search(pattern,i).group() for i in ui]))
```

result:

```
country=2
country=25
country=1
country=6
country=2
```